# Login to fb on any android app with hardcoded credentials and without login popup

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I want to login to facebook with the stored FB credentials hardcoded in my source code and without showing the login popup screen.
I will create a fb account for my application then every time using that credentials fb should be logged in without showing any screen to user.
Can anyone please help me out with this? Is it even possible?

Comment: That sounds highly insecure!

Comment: 1. Make use of SharedPreferences to store those credentials in your local cache.   2. Use sqlite and create a table named credentials to store and fetch those credentials to login.

Comment: @PrajwalW I am not asking about how to store the credentials, i am asking about how we can use hardcoded credentials to login FB without any sso popup or using the native fb android app.

Comment: If Facebook app is installed, then it should do the automatic login. Else it is not possible..

Comment: @KenY-N I know it sounds insecure but we need to do it.

Comment: @sanjeev Requirement is we can't use fb native app and sdk login popup itself.

Comment: Using Facebook Login to implement that sounds quite not right to me.. Maybe implement your own login logic to do that..

Comment: Your question: using hardcoded credetials! Solution: Store that credentials in SP or else store in db so that when you want to login auto, your can fetch from that records and do the part

Comment: I'd do it via an intermediate server that contains the credentials, BTW. Also, I suspect that Facebook wouldn't like a single user logging in from multiple devices.

Comment: Facebook does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to bypass the popup screen that comes for SSO when the Facebook APP is installed. Even If you try using the Web based login method I am sure they would have some code to detect the automated login on their form and they will block you sooner or later. And I am not sure if this webview based popup can be hidden maybe you can try drawing something over it.